# DotNetNuke Lists: Passing both Value and Text data?

Tags: list, text, dotnetnuke, token

In DotNetNuke "Lists", Value is the default data passed when using tokens (for example [Profile:List] would pass the content in the Value column. We need to pass both the Value and Text using tokens. Can anyone advise how this can be done?

Comment: What context are you using these tokens?

Comment: We have a "customer" list where the customer number or unique identifier is stored in the Value field and the customer name is stored in the Text field. We have added a drop down to the Profile Manager in DotNetNuke where the user is then assigned to their respective customer entity from the Customer list. We are doing a form post to a 3rd party and need to pass the Value (which works fine as [Profile:Customer]) and additionally the Text or Customer name as well.

Comment: I've had a ticket with DNN about the way they handle lists types for over 6 months.  They do not handle list types correctly.  It should return the text and not the value.   https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-25763